# Thumbnails of Images in Github Markdown

Tags: image, github, markdown, thumbnails, github-flavored-markdown

Is it possible to render a scaled version of an image (aka. Thumbnail) in my repository in, e.g., the README.md?

I have many (static) high-resolution images which I want to show in the README.md, however, it currently takes very long to fully load the README.md, which I find annoying.

I found a way to scale the image using the HTML-syntax, however, this apparently only changes the appearance of the image, the resolution is still the same, hence, loading the website is not sped up either.

I want the images to span the whole line width, but with lower resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You can add a smaller version of the image with a link to the full resolution one.

`[![sample screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Tkks00R.png)](https://i.imgur.com/Ob4qAwu.png)`

Comment: This requires generating (and committing or uploading) the thumbnails manually, so it's not precisely what I was looking for. However, I didn't consider this yet, I think it's the best workaround so far.